# How can I overlap two flexbox children with position relative in the middle of parent div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an animated hamburger menu icon (three lines and a X when clicked).
But I'm stuck trying to align the first horizontal line and the third one into an X shape.

How can I make two flexbox children overlap each other in the center of the parent div?

Here's what I've done:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#hSandwich'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
   var ct = document.querySelector('#hSandwich');
    var l1 = document.querySelector('.hSandwich-01');
    var l2 = document.querySelector('.hSandwich-02');
    var l3 = document.querySelector('.hSandwich-03');
  l1.classList.toggle('hSandwich-01-x');
    l2.classList.toggle('hSandwich-02-x');
    l3.classList.toggle('hSandwich-03-x');
    ct.classList.toggle('hSandwich-x');
    
  })
})
```

```css
#hSandwich {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

   .hSandwichItem {
    width:60%;
    height:10%;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:grey;
    margin:2px 0 2px 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }

  .hSandwich-01-x {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-50%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  
  .hSandwich-02-x {
    opacity:0;
  }
  
  .hSandwich-03-x {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-50%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div id="hSandwich">
  <div class="hSandwich-01 hSandwichItem"></div>
  <div class="hSandwich-02 hSandwichItem"></div>
  <div class="hSandwich-03 hSandwichItem"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are u expecting like this:

`rotate(45deg)` will rotate the first div towards upward direction and `rotate(-45deg)` will rotate the third div in the downward direction so menu icon will look like this: `>`.Then  just add `margin-top` to third div to get `X` shape

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#hSandwich'), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
   var ct = document.querySelector('#hSandwich');
    var l1 = document.querySelector('.hSandwich-01');
    var l2 = document.querySelector('.hSandwich-02');
    var l3 = document.querySelector('.hSandwich-03');
  l1.classList.toggle('hSandwich-01-x');
    l2.classList.toggle('hSandwich-02-x');
    l3.classList.toggle('hSandwich-03-x');
    ct.classList.toggle('hSandwich-x');
    
  })
})
```

```css
#hSandwich {
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
  border:1px solid black;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
}

   .hSandwichItem {
    width:60%;
    height:10%;
    border-radius:10px;
    background:grey;
    margin:2px 0 2px 0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }

  .hSandwich-01-x {
    position: relative;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
  }
  
  .hSandwich-02-x {
    opacity:0;
  }
  
  .hSandwich-03-x {
   position: relative;
    margin-top: -34%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div id="hSandwich">
  <div class="hSandwich-01 hSandwichItem"></div>
  <div class="hSandwich-02 hSandwichItem"></div>
  <div class="hSandwich-03 hSandwichItem"></div>
</div>
```